# 'local call from' in x64dbg

Tags: windows, ollydbg, functions, x64dbg, tracing

In OllyDbg there was a thing called `"local call from xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx ... "` which helps me know from where a function is being called in the entire module. Does such a feature exist in x64dbg as well?

Answer (score 1):

To find all calls to the given function, select the first line of disassembly of this function and press `Ctrl`+`R`. Then, in `References` window, you will see all calls, sorted increasingly by address.

So, when you know the module starting and ending address (look at the `Symbols` window at `Base` column of this and subsequent module), all listed calls with addresses between them will be the calls from a specific module to that function.